# Как связать Java Servlet с Electron UI

Tags: java, servlet, electron

Есть `desktop` приложение созданное при помощи `Electron`, выглядит оно как форма с одной кнопкой и текстовым полем.

Хочу чтобы по нажатию кнопки данные из поля уходили на `java servlet`(запущен `TomCat`), добавляли к этому тексту **"Hello"** и отправляли назад в текстовое поле формы.

Подскажите, какие технологии мне нужно использовать, чтобы `Electron` и `Java` работали вместе.